# Spring-Roo erase Mysql despite hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, erase

I'm new here and just starting to use Spring Roo.

I have a problem with Roo and Mysql, when the application starts, it delete all the database from Mysql. *I know that for many people the solution was to put update or other "value on hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"* but I tried it and it continues doing the same, when I deploy or redeploy the app, it delete all the data in database, independently of changing "value"(and updating).

I want to "update" the database but don't know other options to solve this. if anyone could help me I would appreciate.

Thanks

(Im using Eclipse Indigo, xampp(apache,mysql,tomcat))

Thanks
(If I stop/start it in the tomcat manager, it also erase the database..)

Comment: A small tip, but if you are starting now with Spring Roo, just don't. Have a look to Spring Boot instead.

Comment: Hi Wim, thanks for answer, for now I'm in the middle of a program and practically i'm forced to use Roo for now, Spring Boot seems a good tool, I would check it in near future. Thanks

Comment: Anyone who knows how to do for not erasing the DB with restart or deploys?

Comment: its is by providing the property you mention, so either you file is not being read, or you are looking at the wrong data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` should be `none`. If you are using maven then do a `clean` and `package` and then run tomcat (`mvn tomcat:run`). The issue is most likely because tomcat is picking up an older version of war.